# Update/Refresh JQuery Mobile Sliders efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, query-optimization

in my App I have several sliders which are updated by events triggered by websockets.
My current src is the following:

```
for (var a = 0; a < data[y].data.length; a++) {
    if (data[y].data[a].changed == 1) {
        var _name = "slider_" + y + "_" + a;
        $("#" + _name).val( data[y].data[a].value).slider("refresh");
    }
}
```

In general my App is not very efficient compared to a native app, and I wonder how i can improve it. Is here any possibility to optimize the code a little bit.

Thx. Peter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much, but you don't need to declare the variable every time:

```
for (var a = 0; a < data[y].data.length; a++) {
    if (data[y].data[a].changed == 1){
        $( ("#slider_" + y + "_" + a) ).val( data[y].data[a].value).slider("refresh");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thx. But I thought more about a more efficient way to manipulate the dom. But I guess there's no alternative instead of refreshing piece by piece.